# How to change background of windows phone designer?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing Windows Phone app in Visual Studio 2013.

By default the phone designer's background is black. It is very hard to design on it if all of my resources (images, font colors, backgrounds) are dark.

Is there any way to change that background to some light color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Device Window (Design -> Device Window menu), you can change the theme from dark to light. This will affect the designer only and will not change your XAML. You can also change the designer accent color and some other properties too.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Set the `<Page>`'s `RequestedTheme` to Light

[image]

Comment: Will this affect the designer screen or the actual page in app?

Comment: @MangeshGhotage It will affect both, as in the design view will be white and when you deploy your application to the phone, it will also be use the white theme.  Why would you want to mismatch them?

Comment: I think this is not available for Silverlight Apps. Or is it?

Answer (score 1):

It simple First click the 
`Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">`

in your xaml.cs page  then go to the properties 
you will see on the top thre is a BRUSH  where you can change the color or your back ground and put background Image ..

```
<Page.Background>
        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Image/Button/yourBgImage.png"/>
    </Page.Background>
```